# Why can't sbt find my custom command with build.scala build definition?

Tags: sbt

Why does sbt not able to find a command in a multiproject build?

My plugin resembles

```
object MyPlugin extends Plugin {

    lazy val plug = Seq( commands ++= Seq(versionWriteSnapshotRelease) )

     def versionWriteSnapshotRelease = Command.command(
         "versionWriteSnapshotRelease",
         "Writes the release format of the snapshot version. This is used to preserve the actual snapshot version in a release commit.",
         ""
     ) { state =>  .... }
}
```

I have my `project/Build.scala` file as follows:

```
lazy val app = Project(id = "app-subproject", base = file("app"))
    .settings(MyPlug.plug :_*)
    .settings(...)

lazy val common = Project(id = "library-subproject", base = file("common"))
    .settings(MyPlug.plug :_*)
    .settings(...)
```

With files laid out like

```
root
|_ common
    |_ src
|_ app
    |_ src
```

This configurations fails with the error:

```
[error] Not a valid command: versionWriteSnapshotRelease
[error] Not a valid project ID: versionWriteSnapshotRelease
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: versionWriteSnapshotRelease (similar: version, ...)
[error] versionWriteSnapshotRelease
```

However if I restructure to something like

```
lazy val app = Project(id = "app-subproject", base = file("."))
    .settings(MyPlug.plug :_*)
    .settings(...)

lazy val common = Project(id = "library-subproject", base = file("common"))
    .settings(MyPlug.plug :_*)
    .settings(...)
```

With files laid out like

```
root
|_ common
    |_ src
|_ src
```

Then it works. Note that my change is to put the `app` project `/src` in the `basedir` and set the `app` project to have base `"."`.

This plugin is used across multiple projects and has no issue when the file layout is in the second form. So I know it isn't an issue with the plugin per-se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you define two submodules `common` and `app` with [the third default root project](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html#Default+root+project) without the command set.

You should add yet another definition of a project for the default root project so the command is also defined for it as follows:

```
lazy val root = Project(id = "root", base = file("."))
    .settings(MyPlug.plug :_*)
    .settings(...)
```

You've confirmed that thinking with your test when you turned `app` into the default root project.

As an additional check before you add the third module definition, do `projects` and see what projects are defined. For every project in the list, execute `[projectName]/versionWriteSnapshotRelease`. I'm sure it's going to be fine for `app` and `common`, but not for the default root module.

Comment: What is the effect of adding in the root project? What does having a root project provide that enables the commands to be found in the sub-projects? Is it something along the lines of commands being put into a ThisBuild or global scope. I guess I'm looking for a mid-level explanation as my SBT foo isn't great yet.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest reading http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html where you find answers to this and few other questions (you may be asking yourself along the way to gain sbt foo).

Comment: I think that the solution is just working partially. I have a multi-project configuration too, and it's true that if you run something like: sbt --> project common --> your custom command, it works. However, if you run directly sbt common/yourCustomCommand it fails. Does anyone know why?

Comment: running `sbt "project common" customCommand` works. not sure why the syntax is different to running a task like `sbt "common/compile"`
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Running-Commands.html